# Is such variant of SAT always satisfiable?

Tags: boolean-algebra, 3-sat

Let we have a SAT instance where every clause has length $\ge3$ (when length $2$ is allowed, it can be unsatisfiable) and each pair of literals appear only once.

Non-example: $(x\lor y\lor z)\land(x\lor y\lor t)$. Here a pair $\{x,y\}$ appears twice.

Example: $(x\lor y\lor z)\land(x\lor\overline y\lor\overline z)$. $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x,\overline y\}$ count as different pairs.

Another example is a clause $(x\oplus y\oplus z)$ reduced to CNF.

So, do there exist an unsatisfiable formula under these restrictions?

Comment: Have you seen: [MU(k)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X00002456)?

Comment: @Evil, how that does help? I hadn't found a proof/counterexample there.

Comment: @Evil, it's interesting that if number of clauses is bounded by $n + \log n$, where $n$ is number of variables, then formula is in $\mathsf{coNP}$.

Comment: Well, I thought that it might be interesting to you, it defines minimal unsatisfiable formula with different constraints so it might be connected, and yes it doesn't answer your question, just the article I thought about after reading your question so only comment.

Comment: Try coding something up to generate random formulas that satisfy this constraint?  My guess would be that if $n$, the number of variables, is large enough, and if you keep adding randomly chosen clauses (that don't violate the constraint) until you can't add any more (without violating the constraint), then with high probability such a randomly chosen formula will be unsatisfiable.  Why don't you code it up, test it, and see what happens?

Comment: @D.W. I don't think it will be fast. I know that subcases as XOR-SAT where any pair of clauses share at most one literal is satisfiable. Same applies to positive SAT where 1 or 2 literals in each clause must be satisfied. The only way is to mix them.

Comment: @rus9384, it doesn't need to be fast.  You can leave it running for an hour or overnight.  If 10 hours of computation time saves you 2 hours of time thinking hard, that's a huge win.